# How do I send a js function to a js file using php

Tags: javascript, php

So I am trying to add a js script into a file using php but when I try this nothing happens.
Am I able to put that type of function in the $content string?

```
    $dirPath = "Test";
    $filename = $dirPath.".js";
    $content = "$(document).ready(function() {$('.Name').load('".$dirpath.".txt');});";
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Can someone please explain to me why it isn't working. Thanks very much.

Comment: is the js file being loaded when rendering the HTML page ? Please check the source code. Also check if accessing the right page.

Comment: Is there any error message? Are permissions are correct?

Comment: There is no error message it just shows nothing